# Generalizing the FFT

Tags: ds.algorithms

Can the divide and conquer nature of the FFT be generalized to other transforms (z Transform, chirp, etc) automatically?

Is there an algorithm that takes in a description of transform (I don't know what information would be needed) and can produce a fast FFT like function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this is not a direct answer, the [following discussion on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10237/does-the-convolution-theorem-apply-to-weaker-algebraic-structures) (Mathoverflow) relates to finding convolution operations that admit fast FFT-like operations on other algebraic structures.